# Weird nullpointer exception error

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app for Android, I am new to app development. In this app I am checking for internet connection on a button click and outputting the result in log buffer but I get a force close with a nullpointerexception on networkcheck boolean

My code is

```
public class Loginpage extends Activity {

private Context context;
private static String TAG = "DH";
private ConnectivityManager connManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginpage);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          if(networkisOk())
        {
                Log.e(TAG, "We have Internet!");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "We don't have Internet!");
        }
      }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.loginpage, menu);
    return true;
}

public final boolean networkisOk()
{
    connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo info = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null)
        return info.isConnected(); // WIFI connected
    else
        return false;
}

}
```

Upon using debugger, the breakpoint of that Nullpointer exception is shown on line

```
connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

The error goes as

```
04-28 22:46:21.259: E/AndroidRuntime(26936): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 22:46:21.259: E/AndroidRuntime(26936):at  com.varun.dev_host.Loginpage.networkisOk(Loginpage.java:52)
```

Can anyone provide me some clue on how I should fix this?

Comment: `context` seems to be NULL

Comment: where r u settting context?

Comment: before `connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();` you need to check if `connManager is null`

Comment: you never initialize the class variable context. Also the networkisOk() method is declared inside an Activity, so you have already a context to retrieve the COnnectionManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to initialize the `context` member

An `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`, so you don't need to declare/initialize a separate `Context` to use. Instead just do;

```
connManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Didn't knew that. thanks, that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Always create this type of method as Utility method.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context ctx) {
        boolean connected = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

            for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
                if ((ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") || ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                        && ni.isConnected()) {
                    connected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return connected;
    }
```